# Django AutoOneToOneField migration and existing entries

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Before starting working on new features, I had this model :

```
class AppUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True) #Django standard user
    # And various standard data that we don't need here
```

Now I needed to extend my database to store more information about the users I have in Django and I came accros [django-annoying](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying) to build relations between like this :

```
class TutorialProgression(models.Model):
    has_seen_home_tutorial = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_seen_revision_tutorial = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    has_seen_lists_tutorial = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class AppUser(models.Model):
    user= models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True) #Django standard user
    # Various standard data
    tutorial_progression = AutoOneToOneField(TutorialProgression)
```

What it does here is that when a new `AppUser` is created, a brand new TutorialProgression would be as well. But I have a problem with existing entries. I tried to migrate my postgres database with theses modifications and it asks me to provide a one-off default or to add a default in my models.

I understand this, but how should I proceed to give each existing `AppUser` a unique `TutorialProgression`?

Comment: From the [documentation](https://github.com/skorokithakis/django-annoying#autoonetoonefield) it seems you're doing it wrong - you should remove `tutorial_progression` from `AppUser` and add `AutoOneToOneField(AppUser)` to `TutorialProgression`; this way `TutorialProgression` will be created on the first call.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this in three stages. Firstly, add the one-to-one with `null=True` and create a migration. Then, create a data migration to loop through all existing AppUsers and create TutorialProgressions for them. Finally, remove the null=True and create a final migration.

Comment: Okay, so I guess there is one one step solution to let the migration handle things, it's kinda annoying when you have to do this in local, then dev server and then again for the production

Comment: What? You create the migrations *once*, then run them everywhere. That part of it should not be any hassle.